# git clone <sshURL> --recursive gives me submoduled with httpsURL in the .git/config and .gitmodules

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-submodules

While cloning the repo with its submodules
`git clone <sshURLofgitrepo> --recursive`

it gives the repo and its submodules

however, the URL of the repo is with the SSH URL
but the URL of submodules is converted to HTTPS
which causes problems later and all HTTPS URLs need to be manually updated to SSH URLS